# Non-negativity of a continuous functions in a ball.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

A quick question that I cannot solve:
Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^k$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(a) > 0$. 
Prove: $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $f(x) > 0$  $\: \forall x \in B(a;\delta)$.

I know that you have to suppose the opposite ($f(x) \leq 0$) and show that it leads to a contradiction.

Got any hints? 
Thanks!
(And sorry for the horrible title, I can't seem to find a better/more descriptive one)

Comment: Let $\epsilon=f(a)/2$... (Argue directly.)

Comment: @OldJohn, $\delta > 0$, so it is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: You don't really need to assume the opposite and show a contradiction, but you could if you wanted to.

Hint 1: You can directly use the definition of continuity: for any ball $B(f(a), \epsilon)$ around $f(a)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, you can find a small ball $B(a, \delta)$ around $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ that maps into $B(f(a), \epsilon)$. If you choose $\epsilon$ so small that every point of $B(f(a), \epsilon)$ is strictly positive, you will be finished. As someone mentioned in the comments, choosing $\epsilon = f(a)/2$ works.

Hint 2: If you really want to assume the opposite and show a contradiction, note that the correct negation of the claim is to assume that "in any $\delta$ ball around $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$, there exists a point $x$ such that $f(x) \le 0$" and show that this contradicts the definition of continuity (see hint 1). But I think this is a bit circuitous, and I think going directly is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous, there is a $\delta > 0$ so that $$|f(a) - f(x)| < f(a)/2$$ for $x \in B(a; \delta)$. Note that this means that 
$$
f(a) - f(x) < f(a)/2
$$
which by rearranging gives
$$
0 < f(a)/2 < f(x)
$$
for all $x \in B(a; \delta)$, as desired.